# Migration from jquery1 to jquery 2 : selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having troubles with selectors and brackets :

```
var myInputId = $(input).attr("id")
"value-5379-32433[]"
```

This is an input id for a checkbox list. I want to select now all the elements having this ID :

```
$("#" + myInputId);
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #value-5379-32433[]
```

It works if I escape the brackets but I find this solution quite ugly as I have to use it in many places :

```
$("#" + inputId.replace("[", "\\[").replace("]", "\\]"))
```

Do you have a nicer solution to this problem ?

EDIT Note : This has to returns many elements as there is many checkboxes with this ID.

EDIT 2 : The html 3 elements I want to select :

```
<div class="type_mlist_check  ">
     <input type="checkbox" id="value-5379-32433[]" value="1" >
     <input type="checkbox" id="value-5379-32433[]" value="2" >
     <input type="hidden"   id="value-5379-32433[]" value="-1">
</div>
```

Comment: `$('[id="' + myInputId + '"]')`. Note that IDs must be unique.

Comment: @undefined you're note is important, I don't have a unique ID, I have 3 checkboxes with same ID, therefore, this does not work :(

Comment: Actually you're wrong, it works for multiple elements

Comment: What is wrong? IDs must not be unique? I know how attribute selectors and ID selectors work so I'm not wrong!

Comment: I mean it works even if IDs aren't unique, it returns an array which is exactly what I want.

Comment: This doesn't mean that IDs can be non-unique. You still have an invalid document according to several W3C standards.

Comment: Therefore I don't know how to build POST arrays in a form beeing a valid W3C standard. (check the html code in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since selector contains meta character use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) instead.

```
$('[id="' + myInputId + '"]');
```

---

Or use a single [`String#replace`](https://www.google.com/search?q=replace&oq=replace&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j69i59l2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) method with character class regex and global modifier.

```
$('# ' + myInputId.replace(/[#;?%&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@]/g,'\\$&'))
```

Comment: I like the first solution but I have 3 elements with this ID, this doesn't work. The second solution looks worse than 2 replaces to me...

Comment: @NicolasThery :  id should be unique..... if there is multiple then use `$('[id="' + myInputId + '"]:first')`

Comment: I want the selector to return all the three elements. (ID may be the same when using Form arrays with `myid[]`)

Comment: @NicolasThery :  `$('[id="' + myInputId + '"]');` -- this one selects multiple